# Neue Ergebnisse und Fragen vom Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache

Tags: discussion, news

Der [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](//www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/) ermittelt über Online-Umfragen die Häufigkeit regionaler Varianten und ist daher eine nützliche Ressource für unsere Seite. Jetzt ist er in die nächste Runde gegangen. Das heißt für uns:

- Die [Ergebnisse der zehnten Runde](//www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-10/) sind veröffentlicht. Hierdurch können ggf. existierende Fragen besser beantwortet werden.
- Die [Fragen zur elften Runde](//www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-11-fragebogen/) sind online. Durch unsere Teilnahme können wir dieses Projekt unterstützen.

Comment: Die Graphikauflösung ist ein mal schlecht (wie früher), mal ein bisschen besser. Jedoch sind sie immer noch Rastergraphiken. Sonst großartig!

Comment: +1 für's Erinnern!

Comment: @c.p.: Die Graphiken sind wirklich extrem schlecht, manchmal kaum lesbar, kennt ihr Möglichkeiten andere Auflösungen zu bekommen?

Comment: @Thomas Ich denke, das Einzige, was eine Chance auf Erfolg haben könnte, ist eine höflich formulierte E-Mail an die Professoren, die den Atlas betreuen. =C